# Как сделать функцию сравнение (== 1:, > 1:) полученных ответов (из базы SQLite) в Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite

Сделал функцию которая ищет преподавателя и передает значение (полное ФИО) в клавиатуру для выбора, а после выбора в другую функцию (которая сохраняет).

**Как разбить результат этой функции, если нашло только одного (`== 1:`) преподавателя передать сразу значение в другую функцию, а если несколько (`> 1:`) то вызывается клавиатура с найденными преподавателями (как в этой функции)?**

Функция:

```
def set_name_teachers(message):
    if message.text == KEYBOARD['GRUPA_CANCEL']:
        msg = f"Отмена"
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg, reply_markup=keyboard)
        return
        
    conn = sqlite3.connect(settings.DATA_BASE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()   
    sql = """SELECT teacher_name FROM import_teachers WHERE lower(teacher_name) like ? ORDER BY teacher_name;"""
    query = "%{}%".format(message.text.casefold())
    query = query.title()
    cursor.execute(sql, (query,))
    teachers_list = cursor.fetchall()
    if not teachers_list:
        sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не могу найти преподавателя с такой фамилией. Попробуйте еще раз.')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, set_name_teachers)
        return
    else:    
        kb_teach_grup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
        msg = f"Выберите из списка:"
        for ln in teachers_list:
            kb_teach_grup.row(ln[0])
        kb_teach_grup.row(KEYBOARD['TEACHER_CANCEL'])
        sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg, reply_markup=kb_teach_grup, parse_mode='HTML')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, add_user_teacher)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно простое условие, проверяющее количество преподавателей в списке:

```python
    if not teachers_list:
        # код для ситуации, если преподавателей нет
        ...

    elif len(teachers_list) == 1:
        # код для ситуации, если преподаватель один
        ...

    else:
        # код для ситуации, если преподавателей несколько
        ...
```